# Hide/reset what a Macintosh knows about a downloaded file?

Tags: macos, mac

So what my question is that is it possible to remove what Mac knows about a file.

For example:

What I’ve noticed is having the setting, “Allow apps downloaded from: Mac App store and identified developers” obviously doesn’t allow me to open an unidentified app downloaded on the Macintosh.

But, I’ve been able to download that same app—or even Java applet I’ve tried—on a different computer, and transfer it over via USB and run it. No security, unidentified developer warnings.

So my question is is it possible to “remove” its knowledge of it being downloaded on my Macintosh? I’m not sure how it keeps track of what has come from where, but that’d be interesting to know also.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to clear the 'where from' metadata

If you run xattr on your downloaded file, like this:

`xattr /Path/To/File`

You'll get a key named `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` To delete this key in the Terminal, run:

`xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms /Path/To/File`

However, if you think you'll need to do this often, then you can use this Applescript, saved as an application & simply drag & drop your files to it to clear the data…

```
on deleteWhereFrom(fileToClean)
    try
        set posixPath to quoted form of POSIX path of fileToClean
        do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms " & posixPath
    end try
end deleteWhereFrom
on open imgs
    repeat with i in imgs
        deleteWhereFrom(i)
    end repeat
end open
on run
    set imgs to choose file with multiple selections allowed
    repeat with i in imgs
        deleteWhereFrom(i)
    end repeat
end run
```

*Source* [Delete 'Where From' metadata from files](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20101206161739274)

Comment: Thanks, I do know you can open it like that, but, I would like to know the process of removing something like that.

Comment: .. .Done. ..;-)

Comment: super useful for files that adobe cc can't sync for this reason :)

Comment: Any reason why I have to throw files twice on AppleScript under OS X 10.15 (Catalina) to get effect? Thank you

Comment: @vklidu - Sorry, not a clue I'm afraid. I don't have a single Mac in the building that can run Catalina. Maybe try asking it as a new question & refer back to this one for context.